# Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException coming from I/O misuse?

Tags: java, io, nosuchelementexception

I wrote this program to act as a seating chart for an airplane. I am fairly new with using I/O in Java, and I am getting these runtime errors:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException

at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java: 862)

at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java: 1371)

at AirplaneSeatProgram.main(AirplaneSeatProgram.java:27)
```

I think this has something to do with closing I/O too soon (specifically in line 27 of the code?), but I am not sure. Could someone help me with this? I will post the code below.

```
import java.util.*; //imports all java.util classes
import java.io.*; //importa all java.io classes

public class AirplaneSeatProgram{

   //main method
   public static void main(String[] args){

      //constructs a Scanner object to accept input
      Scanner myScanner=new Scanner(System.in);

      //creates an input stream object linked to the file
      Scanner inputStream;
      char[][] mySeatMap=new char[9][8];
      //tries to access the file
      try{
         inputStream=new Scanner(new FileInputStream("seatsmap.txt"));
         for (int i=0; i<mySeatMap.length; i++){
            for (int j=0; j<mySeatMap[i].length; j++){
               //mySeatMap[i][j]=inputStream.next().charAt(0);
               mySeatMap[i][j]=inputStream.next().charAt(0);
            }
         }
      }
      //if the file doesn't exist, create a file
      catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
         for (int i=0; i<mySeatMap.length; i++){
            for (int j=0; j<mySeatMap[i].length; j++){
               mySeatMap[i][j]='.';
            }
         }
      } 

      //displays a menu for the user to select an operation until the user selects "Exit"
      int myChoice=0;
      while (myChoice!=3){
         System.out.println();
         System.out.println("Please select an operation:");
         System.out.println("1: Reserve a seat");
         System.out.println("2: Free a seat");
         System.out.println("3: Exit");
         myChoice=myScanner.nextInt();
         display(mySeatMap);

         //if the user selects 1, call the reserve() method
         if (myChoice==1){
            //checks to see if the input is valid
            String regex="[0-9][a-hA-H]";
            System.out.println("Enter a seat number (ex. 4C):");
            String seatNumber=myScanner.next();
            boolean isValid=isValid(seatNumber, regex);
            int row=row(seatNumber);
            int column=column(seatNumber);
            System.out.println("row="+row);
            System.out.println("column="+column);
            //if the input is valid and the seat is available, reserve the seat
            if (isValid){
               if (mySeatMap[row][column]=='.'){
                  reserve(mySeatMap, row, column);
               }
               else{
                  System.out.println("Seat already taken.");
               }
            }
            //otherwise throw an error
            else{
               InvalidSeatException e=new InvalidSeatException();
               e.toString();
            }
         }

         //if the user selects 2, call the free() method
         if (myChoice==2){
            //checks to see if the input is valid
            String regex="[0-9][a-hA-H]";
            System.out.println("Enter a seat number (ex. 4C):");
            String seatNumber=myScanner.next();
            boolean isValid=isValid(seatNumber, regex);
            int row=row(seatNumber);
            int column=column(seatNumber);
            //if the input is valid and the seat is unavailable, free the seat
            if (isValid){
               if (mySeatMap[row][column]!='.'){
                  free(mySeatMap, row, column);
               }
               else{
                  System.out.println("Seat already free.");
               }
            }
            //otherwise throw an error
            else{
               InvalidSeatException e=new InvalidSeatException();
               e.toString();
            }
         }

         if (myChoice==3){
            //creates an output stream object linked to a file
            PrintWriter outputStream;
            try{
               outputStream=new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream("seatsmap.txt"));
               for (int i=0; i<mySeatMap.length; i++){
                  for (int j=0; j<mySeatMap[i].length; j++){
                     outputStream.print(mySeatMap[i][j]+" ");
                  }
                  outputStream.println();
               }
            }
            catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
               System.out.println("Cannot create file because the file cannot be found.");
               System.exit(0);
            }
         }

         //if the user enters an invalid number from the menu, tell them to try again
         if (myChoice>3){
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("Invalid selection. Please try again.");
         }
      }
   }

    //method to reserve a seat
    public static void reserve(char[][] a, int r, int c){
       a[r][c]='x';
       System.out.println("Successfully reserved your seat.");
    }

    //method to free a seat
    public static void free(char[][] a, int r, int c){
       a[r][c]='.';
       System.out.println("Successfully freed the seat.");
    }

   //method to determine if seat is valid
   public static boolean isValid(String a, String b){
      if (!a.matches(b)){
         return false;
      }
      else{
         return true;
      }
   }

   //method to return the row
   public static int row(String a){
      char b=a.charAt(0);
      int c=Character.getNumericValue(b);  
      return c;
   }

   //method to return the column
   public static int column(String a){
      char b=a.charAt(0);
      int c=(Character.getNumericValue(b))-2;
      if(c>10){
         int d=(Character.getNumericValue(b))-2;
         return d;
      }
      else{
         return c;
      }
   }

   //method to display the seating chart
   public static void display(char[][] a){
      System.out.println();
      System.out.println("   A  B  C  D  E  F  G  H");
      for (int i=0; i<9; i++){
         System.out.print(i+1);
         for (int j=0; j<8; j++){
            System.out.print("  "+a[i][j]);
         }
         System.out.println();
      }
   }

}
```

Comment: well, maybe there are not enough characters in the file? where is the line `27`?

Comment: could you provide the content of `seatsmap.txt`?

Comment: Check null here inputStream.next().

Comment: @JohnnyAW line 27 says "mySeatMap[i][j]=inputStream.next().charAt(0);"

Comment: @JohnnyAW the content of seatsmap.txt is the array created in the catch block where I am creating the inputStream

Comment: @SmartCoder I am not sure what you mean by that. Would you please explain?

Comment: if (inputStream.next() != null)

Comment: @SmartCoder where in the code should I implement this?

Comment: @Hannah no, you are reading a file from the disk. What is the content of the file? The Exception `NoSuchElementException` tells you, that you are trying to read next token from the stream, but there is no tokens left. Either your file is empty or it has not enough tokens to read...

Comment: @SmartCoder Scanner.next() will never return null, under any circumstances.

Comment: @JohnnyAW I got some help from my professor, and my issue was that I ran the program once without having outputStream.close() in my first try block. My program was trying to read from the empty file, like you said. I just had to remove the file from my computer, implement outputStream.close(), and I was good to go.